# "No more data to read from socket" Exception Tomcat DBCP

Tags: database, tomcat, oracle10g, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using tomcat's DBCP with Oracle 10g. After using the connections successfully, when some time passes, there are no more connections available. I receive this exception

**No more data to read from socket**

On next retry this exception occurs:

**OALL8 is in an inconisitent state**

On next retry this exception occurs:

**Io exception: Software caused connection abort: socket write error**

After that this exception occurs:

**Closed Connection**

My question is what is the reason of these exceptions? Are they due to some bug in DBCP or Oracle Database is causing the issue.

I'm using Tomcat 6, jdk 1.7, Oracle 10.2

Comment: Stack traces? Are you using "abandoned" connection detection? If not, enable it and see if you get warnings about that kind of thing. Have you Googled for "OALL8"? The top link right now says "you are using an array that is too big". Could that be your problem?

Comment: Adding below lines in the Resource tag solved the problem but still couldn't figure out the actual problem.

**validationQuery="select * from dual"
testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true" testWhileIdle="true"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000" numTestsPerEvictionRun="3"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="1800000"**

Comment: Try reducing all that junk to simply `validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"` (don't use `SELECT *`, it just makes you look like you don't know what you're doing) and see if that helps.